# Encoding attributes in an Genetic Algorithm

Tags: python, encoding, genetic-algorithm, deap

Genetic Algorithm, Python, Deap

I am writing python code to use a genetic algorithm to choose the parameters of an LSTM neural network. In my case I would like to work with window-size and units. Is it better to create two random integers or use bitstrings?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.